# How to move a jira ticket from one project to another using API/python module

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, python-jira

I've been following the JIRA python module guide on https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/
I couldn't find a way to move a ticket/issue from one project to another, or perhaps change the issue type from subtask to a task. 
Is there a way to do this using the python module or an API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to move a ticket from project X to project Y. The workaround I found for this was to create a new ticket with the relevant data from the original ticket and the desired new issue type. Afterwards you can delete the original ticket.